# Show two path homotopy classes are equal?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am trying to show that $[q \circ \lambda]= [q \circ \mu]$ where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are the paths in $I × I$ defined by

\begin{equation}
    \lambda(t)=
    \begin{cases}
      (2t,0), &  0 \leq t \leq 1/2 \\
      (1,2t-1), & 1/2 \leq t \leq 1
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
    \mu(t)=
    \begin{cases}
      (0,2t), &  0 \leq t \leq 1/2 \\
      (2t-1,1), & 1/2 \leq t \leq 1
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

and $q : I × I → (I × I)/∼ $ is the quotient map to the Klein bottle.
I don't think it should be too difficult but am a little confused about the details.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am guessing I have to find a homotopy, but  can't work out how it should look.

Comment: Here's a starting point: if you could find a homotopy from $\lambda$ to $\mu$, then you'd have a homotopy from $q \circ \lambda$ to $q \circ \mu$. Can you explain why? If so, add that to your question --- click on "edit" just beneath the question itself --- so we can see more of what you know.  Have you drawn $\lambda$ and $\mu$? At least one obvious answer will involve intermediate paths that have *three* parts in their definitions rather than the two parts in $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Less obvious solutions can ve done with just two parts.

Comment: I have tried, I believe they give the sides of the $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ square?

Comment: That's right, $\lambda$ travels right and the up the outside of the square, and $\mu$ goes up then right. Can you write down a homotopy between these paths that fixes the endpoints? (Hint: one way is to use the fact that the square is *convex*: by definition $X\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex iff for any pair of points $x, y\in X$ and $s\in I$ the convex combination $sx + (1-s)y$ is still in $X$.)

Comment: I think I can imagine the homotopy, but I'm not sure what the formula for it would be. I think it would look like a series of lines within the square, all starting at $(0,0)$ and ending at $(1,1)$, starting at the paths we have defined already and contracting to the $x=y$ line?

Comment: Yes I think you have the picture that I had in mind. Now you should figure out how to use the definition of convexity to help you write down this homotopy. (If you're still having trouble, try googling "straight line homotopy".)

Comment: Alternatively, you could argue that $(q\circ\lambda)\cdot\overline{(q\circ\mu)}$ is null-homotopic because it bounds a region homeomorphic to a disk (where $\cdot$ is loop concatenation and $\overline{\gamma}$ is path reversal). Then use the fact that homotopy classes of loops form a group to deduce that $[q\circ\lambda] = [q \circ \mu]$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a concept of a "straight line homotopy" between maps to a convex space, which you can use to show that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are homotopic relative endpoints as maps to $I\times I$. From this it follows that $q\circ \lambda \sim q\circ\mu$.

Say the space $Y \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is *convex* if for every two points $y_0, y_1\in Y$ the straight line between them is entirely contained in $Y$. More explicitly, for all $s\in I$ the *convex combination* $(1-s)y_0 + sy_1$ remains in $Y$. (You should convince yourself that the straight line between $y_0$ and $y_1$ really is parametrized this way).

Now, given two continuous functions $f, g\colon X \to Y$ where $Y\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex, we can define the *straight line homotopy* 
$$ H(x, s) = (1-s)f(x) + sg(x) $$
which is continuous because it is a linear combination of continuous functions, and its image is contained in $Y$ by convexity. Moreover, this homotopy is constant on every $x$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$. In particular, if $f$ and $g$ are paths with the same start- and end-points then $H$ is a homotopy fixing end-points.

**Caution:** There are many cases where the straight line homotopy is not the correct thing to consider. In particular if the space $Y$ you're mapping into isn't convex then the homotopy won't necessarily stay in the space, and if $Y$ isn't a subspace of a vector space then the convex combination doesn't even make sense. It really depends on the situation and what you're trying to prove.